# How to compare two csv files?

Tags: python, csv

I have a **csv file1** which is like

```
FLAGSTAFF   AZ  50244.67    5.02    KA1_Podium_Garage_S
FLAGSTAFF   AZ  33752.13    3.38    KA1_Podium_Garage_S
FLAGSTAFF   AZ  11965.5      1.2    KA1_Podium_Garage_S
FLAGSTAFF   AZ  3966.48      0.4    KA1_Podium_Garage_S
SEATTLE     WA  12646.9      1.26   KA1_Podium_Garage_S
SEATTLE     WA  225053.92   22.51   KA1_Podium_Garage_S
SEATTLE     WA  23974.3      2.4    KA1_Podium_Garage_S
SEATTLE     WA  7036.4       0.7    KA1_Podium_Garage_S
SEATTLE     WA  3021.93      0.3    KA1_Podium_Garage_S
```

I have a csv file 2 which is like ,

```
Alabama     AL  1
Alaska      AK  2
Arizona     AZ  4
Arkansas    AR  5
California  CA  6
Colorado    CO  8
Connecticut CT  9
SEATTLE     WA  53
```

Now i have to append the third column value  from csv file2 to csv file1,
by comparing second column

For example  it should look like,

AZ code is 4
WA code is 53
wherever AZ,WA is there in my csv file1 , the code should get appended into a column

My output should look like,

```
FLAGSTAFF   AZ  50244.67    5.02    KA1_Podium_Garage_S 4
FLAGSTAFF   AZ  33752.13    3.38    KA1_Podium_Garage_S 4
FLAGSTAFF   AZ  11965.5      1.2    KA1_Podium_Garage_S 4
FLAGSTAFF   AZ  3966.48      0.4    KA1_Podium_Garage_S 4
SEATTLE     WA  12646.9      1.26   KA1_Podium_Garage_S 53
SEATTLE     WA  225053.92   22.51   KA1_Podium_Garage_S 53
SEATTLE     WA  23974.3      2.4    KA1_Podium_Garage_S 53
SEATTLE     WA  7036.4       0.7    KA1_Podium_Garage_S 53
SEATTLE     WA  3021.93      0.3    KA1_Podium_Garage_S 53
```

Here is the code which i tried,

```
with open("/home/sumit/Desktop/CSV_FILE1.csv", "r") as f:
    first = {rows[1]: rows[0:] for rows in list(csv.reader(f))}

# compare second csv and append Code
with open("CSVFILE2.csv", "r") as f1:
    for row in csv.reader(f1):
        if row[1] in first:
            first[row[1]].append(row[2])

# convert dict back to list
merged = [(k,) + tuple(v) for k, v in first.items()]

# write list to output csv
with open("output.csv", "w") as f1:
    csv.writer(f1).writerows(merged)
```

Output am getting like,

```
AZ  FLAGSTAFF   AZ  44230.4 4.42    KA1_Podium_Garage_S 4
WA  SEATTLE     WA  45329.3 4.53    KA1_Podium_Garage_S 53
```

Comment: a `dict` can only have one value for each key; if you try to add a key multiple times with different values, it will only take the latest one

Comment: I suggest switching your logic: your second csv file seems to only have one instance of each state. make a dict with that csv where the keys: val pairs are the state: numbers then iterate through the first csv and append the values as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is creating a dictionary, based on state abbreviation, from your first file.  This looks wrong, since a dictionary can only have each key once, and you have multiple rows with "AZ" for example.

```
first = { rows[1]: rows[0:] for rows in list(csv.reader(f)) }
```

Instead, you should make your dictionary based on the second file:

```
with open("CSVFILE2.csv", "r") as f1:
    code = { row[1]: row[2] for row in csv.reader(f1) }
```

Then, loop over your first file, and append the appropriate code to each row.

```
with open("/home/sumit/Desktop/CSV_FILE1.csv", "r") as f:
    merged = [ row + [code[row[1]]] for row in csv.reader(f) ]
```

And write out the merged data to the new file.

---

Explanation of `row + [code[row[1]]]`:

If row is `["FLAGSTAFF", "AZ", 50244.67, 5.02, "KA1_Podium_Garage_S"]`, then

- `row[1]` is `"AZ"`,
- `code[row[1]]` is `code["AZ"]` which is `4`,
- `[code[row[1]]]` is the list `[4]`
- and `row + [code[row[1]]` is list concatenation, producing the desired new row value: `["FLAGSTAFF", "AZ", 50244.67, 5.02, "KA1_Podium_Garage_S", 4]`